# Error in Icon Image of Context Menu

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I m getting error after running the application "error:Sys.InvalidOperationException: ImageError error #4001 in control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Xaml': AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR"
in below code

```
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Accoustics">
            <toolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image x:Name="menuIcon1" Source="Images//Arrow.PNG" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="Fill"/>
                </toolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
            </toolkit:MenuItem>
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
```

strange thing is that i m able to see image in design view.

any idea??

Thanks.
-Nitin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is correct the path Source="Images//Arrow.PNG"?
Try the correct path Source="Images/Arrow.PNG"